# How to create custom URI handler to retrieve image resources in DLL file?

Tags: html, dll, resources, uri, custom-protocol

I have several image files embedded as resources in a DLL file! I want to create my own custom protocol handler to be able to write HTML code to access these resources.

For example, on a computer where this DLL is located I want to be able to (in IE) run HTML code like this:

< IMG SRC="customuri://res/image01.jpg"/ >

This should always point to my DLL, containing the image01.jpg as a embedded resource!

Comment: I believe that custom protocol handlers must be registered with the OS, and possibly the browser, in order to function.